# JSF multiple groups of selectOneRadio on a page: how to recover the values?

Tags: jsf, selectoneradio

I have a jsf page with multiple radiobutton groups (dynamically generated) on it. I need to retrieve the values from it in a backing bean, but fails to do so.

The business: a user wants to subscribe to a course that consists of multiple groups of coursedays. The user can choose the coursedays. So if a course consists of for example 4 coursedays, organised in 3 different groups, the user can choose from 12 coursedays, in blocks of 3.

The relevant part of the xhtml-page:

```
<c:forEach var="cd1" items="#{coursedayBean.getCoursedays(groupBean.getFirstGroup}">
  <h:selectOneRadio value="#{subscriptionBean.selectedCoursedays[cd1.sequenceNr]}" >
    <f:selectItems value="#{coursedayBean.getCoursedaysSelectItems}"/>
  </h:selectOneRadio>
</c:forEach>
```

This results in a n*m matrix of radiobuttons where I want to retrieve n values.
The selectItems are of type `<Long, String>`.

In my backing bean, I declared the following:

```
public List<String> getSelectedCoursedays() {
  return selectedCoursedays;
}

public void setSelectedCoursedays(List<String> selectedCoursedays) {
  this.selectedCoursedays = selectedCoursedays;
}
```

I tried with a Map, List, but none of them worked. The setSelectedCoursedays is never called.
How do I declare the array/list/map to get the values in my backing bean?

```
#{subscriptionBean.selectedCoursedays[cd1.sequenceNr]}
```

doesn't do the trick.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is miss understanding between `c:forEach` and `ui:repeat`. `c:forEach` will not build `UI component tree nodes`. Firstly, you have to reference difference between them [here](https://rogerkeays.com/jsf-c-foreach-vs-ui-repeat).

Comment: Thanks, that actually was the reason.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. This can't be the reason. The explanation "will not build UI component tree nodes" applies to `<ui:repeat>` only, the `<c:forEach>` definitely builds them (the `<ui:repeat>` only renders them), but this is thus definitely not the cause at all.

Answer (score 0):

This construct should work just fine. The setter will indeed never be called. JSF/EL just calls the setter on `ArrayList` itself by the `add(index, object)` method. I.e. it does basically:

```
subscriptionBean.getSelectedCoursedays().add(cd1.sequenceNr, selectedItem);
```

I'm not sure how you observed the concrete problem of "it doesn't work". Perhaps you were firing an ajax request and putting a breakpoint on the setter method and didn't read the server logs. There are two possible cases where this construct will fail.

1. If you don't prepare the `selectedCoursedays` with `new ArrayList()`, then you will get `PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, 'selectedCoursedays' returned null`.
2. If you don't fill the `selectedCoursedays` with the same amount of `null` items as the course days, then you will get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

So, you should prepare the `selectedCoursedays` as follows:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    selectedCoursedays = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < coursedays.size(); i++) {
        selectedCoursedays.add(null);
    }
}
```

Easier alternative is to make it a `String[]`.

```
private String[] selectedCoursedays;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    selectedCoursedays = new String[coursedays.size()];
}
```